# Comobox selected value not correctly getting in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, combobox

Now I am trying to implement Combobox in WPF. When I select the Combo box first, I got an empty value,.

Second time onwards i got previous selected value in combo.

```
1st - Empty - When I select Candy 
2nd - Candy - when I select Frog 
.... 
....
```

How Can I get the Combobox selected value when I select Candy - value also want to be candy.

### My code

```
 <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="674,14,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Candy" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Edge" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Frog" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Inc" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Mercury" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Metal" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Sleek" />
                    </ComboBox>
```

## My C# Code

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + comboBox1.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Combobox items has Content, So if you want the Selected item Try the below code,.

```
 if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)

    {

    ComboBoxItem cbItem = (ComboBoxItem) comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    MessageBox.Show(cbItem.Content.ToString());

    }
```

I hope it is help full, and if it help accept my answer.

Comment: now i realize why i am not get the output, while tring selected items and selected values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("" + ((ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedValue).Content);
    }
```